# PostgreSQL - Return the row content when UPDATE fails

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

When updating a row with PostgreSQL (through the UPDATE statement), this is possible to get back the modified row content using `RETURNING *`.

I would like to know if there is any way to get the unmodified row when the update fails because of constraints. For example, executing the following command (with `RETURNING *`) does not return the current row values:

```
UPDATE sentence
SET content = 'This is a sentence', language_id=834
WHERE id = '0538f24a-2046-4da6-933d-409aa7b7c597'
RETURNING *;
```

it gives the error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sentence_language_id_content_key"
DETAIL:  Key (language_id, content)=(834, This is a sentence) already exists.
```

Is there any way to return the unmodified row content or does `RETURNING *` only work when a data modification actually happened without any constraint error ?

Comment: You mean, you would like to ignore the conflicting rows to avoid the error message?

Comment: No. I want the constraint to be applied and to block the update if required (like the example). But, as an answer, instead of getting an error, I want to get the unmodified row content (as RETURNING does when no error occurs).

Answer (score 2):

One option to keep using update and still returning the conflicting rows would be to create a function that does this check before you perform the update. In case the the primary key already exists, it returns the conflicting row, and If not, the row gets updated. An example of such a function could be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(cont TEXT, lang INT, idp TEXT) 
RETURNS SETOF sentence AS $$
DECLARE j RECORD;
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM sentence WHERE content = cont AND 
                               language_id = lang INTO j;
  IF j IS NOT NULL THEN 
    RETURN NEXT j;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY UPDATE sentence SET content = cont, language_id= lang 
                 WHERE id = idp RETURNING *;
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN SQLSTATE '23505' THEN 
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM sentence WHERE content = cont AND
                                            language_id= lang;
END$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT my_func('This is a sentence',834,'0538f24a-2046-4da6-933d-409aa7b7c597');
```

**EDIT**: If there is no conflict and you still want the `RETURNING *`, just add a `RETURN QUERY` to the `UPDATE` statement:

```
...    
RETURN QUERY 
UPDATE sentence SET content = cont, language_id= lang WHERE id = idp 
RETURNING *;
...
```

Comment: If you have 2 connections executing this at the same time, one will probably succeed and the other will probably get a unique_violation exception

Comment: @eurotrash thanks for pointing out. I add a catch to the function, despite the odds.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.