# How to return original row in Postgres upon violating a unique constraint

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, if you try to insert a value that has a Unique Index on it, you'll see the following:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "testing_email_key"
 DETAIL: Key (email)=(email@domain.com) already exists.
```

In my case, I actually (upon failing this way) want the original row with `email` = `email@domain.com`. Sort of like a `RETURNING` statement, but for a failed insert.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

Right now I actually just parse the error message in Python above, then re-issue a `SELECT` to get the original row, but seems like this is something that should be able to be done in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is not possible to do in a single query, you'll need to use a function to check the original row, that it's exactly what you're doing then in Python. You can see more information in the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

If you want to perform the wish behaviour in postgresql instead of Python, you can do a pgplsql function, catch the exception and do the `SELECT` statement (some questions related with this solution: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49635484/6796652) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168169))

**Edit**
This could be the alternative pgplsql solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_insert_row(
    param_email varchar)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    result integer;

BEGIN
  /*
  -- To Test:
    SELECT udf_insert_row('admin@admin.com'); will return 1
    SELECT udf_insert_row('admin2@admin.com'); will return 2
    SELECT udf_insert_row('admin@admin.com'); will return 1
  */

  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO your_table(
        email
        ) 
      VALUES (
        param_email
      ) RETURNING id INTO result;
  EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
      SELECT 
        id INTO STRICT result
      FROM 
        your_table 
      WHERE 
        email = param_email;
  END;  

    RETURN result;

END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION udf_insert_row(varchar)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Then in python, you can call the function like this:

```
pgcur.execute("BEGIN")
args = ["admin@admin.com"]
pgcur.callproc("udf_insert_row",args)
result = pgcur.fetchone()
pgcur.execute("COMMIT")
```

You can accept this as a valid answer if it's useful

Comment: got it. is there a way to do it all in one function call though? I just figure having postgres do all the work is far better than in python performance wise

Comment: I updated my answer with the pgplsql alternative solution, this should be of your help