# Django unique ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a PlaceType model related to the Place model via a M2M field. It functions as necessary where I do place.type.create(name='foo') but it ends up having duplicate values for name=foo. That leads to a large amount of duplicate data. I would like the PlaceType table to be unique in the name field. I tried to add unique=True but it throws an error when inserting. I would essentially want to do a get_or_create on the type but in an elegant way.

```
class Place
    ...

class PlaceType
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place,related_name="types")
```

Thank you!

Comment: The reason it raises an error is (likely) because there is already data in the database that is not unique. You should first fix the problem at the database, and *then* migrate.

Comment: I emptied the entire DB before migrating. When I insert 2 fresh rows for ```name='foo'``` I end up getting an error on the second row because it's trying to insert a new row with ```name='foo'``` in the PlaceType table but ends up violating the unique constraint

Comment: you can perform a `.get_or_create` on the `PlaceType`, and then `.add(..)` it to the m2m.

Comment: That would involve 3 hits (get > create > add) on the DB which I'm trying to avoid. I was hoping there was a way to do something like an INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE kind of insert.

Comment: but the `.create(..)` performs two queries already: a create `PlaceType`, and then an add. See here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L561 and here https://github.com/django/django/blob/a3fc24f01484d4bdd106bc6d7c49049fc5352af6/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L1014

Comment: I don't think you can do better with a `ManyToManyField`. Are you sure you need each Place to have multiple PlaceTypes? Are you concerned about the number of queries because you're creating multiple PlaceTypes at once?

Comment: The dataset I'm importing has multiple place types for each place and until I've figured out a way to prune it down correctly I have to go with multiple types for now. The number of types are usually between 2-4 but they are repetitive categories.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're just stuck with the "extra" query then. There isn't a db-level `get_or_create`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897282/how-to-return-original-row-in-postgres-upon-violating-a-unique-constraint